# MinGW and Perl conflict regarding IncludePath

Tags: c++, perl, visual-studio-code

I have installed MinGW and StrawberryPerl and now whenever I type `gcc -v` the version installed with StrawberryPerl is executed. But I want to execute the MinGW version, because otherwise my VS Code setup gives me the error:

> cannot open source file "vcruntime.h" (dependency of "iostream")

But besides that error message my program still is compiled and works.

How is that possible?

Additional Informations:
I am on Windows 10.
The output when I run `gcc -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64- 
mingw32/7.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-7.1.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='x86_64-posix-seh, Built by strawberryperl.com project' CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/opt/build/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v502/mingw64/opt/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/opt/build/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v502/mingw64/opt/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS=' -I/opt/build/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v502/mingw64/opt/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' LDFLAGS='-pipe -fno-ident -L/opt/build/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v502/mingw64/opt/lib -L/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib '
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by strawberryperl.com project)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is determined by your PATH variable. If both MinGW gcc and Strawberry gcc are present in the PATH, the one which is listed first will be executed. So if you want MinGW gcc, you can go edit the PATH and move the MinGW directory higher up in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I have now installed MinGW after I installed Perl and everything works fine. I do however not really know what the Issue was...